# Find the difference equation for {2, 4, 16, 256, ...}

Tags: mathematical-modeling, recurrence-relations

Write a difference equation to represent the change during the nth interval as a function of the previous term in the sequence.

b. {2,4,16, 256,...}

I know that a<sub>n</sub>= 2<sup>2<sup>n</sup></sup> but I can't figure out how to find Δa<sub>n</sub> = c*a<sub>n</sub>.

I'm lost. I'd really appreciate some help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The ratio $a_n/a_{n-1}$ is always $a_{n-1}$. So the term difference is
$$
\Delta a_n \equiv a_n-a_{n-1} = a_{n-1}^2 - a_{n-1} = ( a_{n-1} -1) a_{n-1}
$$
If you insist on writing this as $c \cdot a_n$ the form would be
$$
\Delta a_n = \frac{a_{n-1}-1}{a_{n-1}} a_n
$$